# Why does 'Generate DB DOC' in SQL Developer fill my filesystem with Flashback data

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer : 2.1.1.64

When I generate DB doc on my tables my file system fills up with files like _Flashback.html.

How can I prevent this?

Who on earth might be interested in this data as part of a database documentation?

IMHO this should not be included in 'DB Doc'

This data is displayed :

```
Operation   VERSIONS_XID    VERSIONS_STARTSCN   VERSIONS_ENDSCN     ROW_ID  NOW_SCN

Original    null    null    null    oracle.sql.ROWID@10c59ca    77837230355
Original    null    null    null    oracle.sql.ROWID@1dae16a    77837230355
Original    null    null    null    oracle.sql.ROWID@104fb34    77837230355
Original    null    null    null    oracle.sql.ROWID@81371          77837230355
Original    null    null    null    oracle.sql.ROWID@349826     77837230355
```

Regards,
Rob

Comment: You should try this on Serverfault as well.

Comment: What do you mean by 'filesystem'? Like the whole filesystem or the output directory? I don't even know where to look for these files. And my SQLDeveloper version is precisely the same!

Comment: I meant the output directory. It generates a HTML page with all the available flasback data for every table. This takes forever and generates a lot of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an acknowledged bug that should be fixed in the next release. I simply delete them for now but, they can be large (GBs).

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10215086&tstart=0
" Bug 13683879: 3.1EA3: FORUM: GENERATE DB DOC SHOULD NOT INCLUDE TABLE FLASHBACK DATA
  Fixed and will be in next release.

Brian Jeffries
  SQL Developer Team"